# Plugin for setting up a gallery with albums and photos WordPress

Tags: wordpress

One of my client needs a photo gallery on their website to be built. They have 1000s of images of different events. I have questions on how to approach this.

1. What is a good way of organizing the images on the "Gallery page"?
2. What is a good plugin I can use?
3. Should I host the images on my web hosting (shared) or host it in flickr or similar and show thumbnails here? If so what plugin should I use?

Any suggestions and links to live examples?

Comment: IMO, the question is off-topic for 2 reasons: *too broad* (too many possible answers) and *asking for recommendations* (aka "shopping question"). See [help/dont-ask].

Comment: @brasofilo How is this broad? The answer by redleaf with 3 lines and a link below pretty much explains all of my questions. Whats wrong with asking for recommendations? Sorry just curious.

Comment: [Here's a good explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223458/185667) about *too broad*. And recommendation questions, in the classic [Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).

Answer (score 1):

Importing thousands of images to Wordpress could get incredibly tedious, and you may run into memory errors in the process.  My suggestion would be to store the images on Flickr, and feed them in using a plugin.  There are many good Flickr plugins to choose from, but here's one that seems to be popular.
http://wordpress.org/plugins/awesome-flickr-gallery-plugin/